# how to configure component pubsub to tigase server in ubuntu machine(localhost)?

Tags: linux, localhost, publish-subscribe, tigase

I have installed tigase server in my linux machine.

After successfully installed tigase i found following in **etc/init.properties**.

```
--user-db = mysql
--admins = admin@username
--user-db-uri = jdbc:mysql://localhost/tigasedb?user=tigase&password=tigase12
config-type = --gen-config-def
--virt-hosts = username
--debug = server
```

Now, I want to install pubsub component with already installed server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall with advance configuration options instead of basic installation.

You will get options for which component you need to configure with server.